# EWS API send email gives error "The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

I wrote an Outlook web add-in that uses the [EWS API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices) to read email properties, including the MIME content, and process the data outside Outlook. This all works fine.

A new requirement has come in to be able to send a draft email by clicking a button in the task pane. I implemented this using the [`EmailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.sendandsavecopy?view=exchange-ews-api) method. This call failed with a `ServiceResponseException` message `"The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application."`

I investigated, and found that I needed to [increase the permissions requested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions) in the addin manifest to the highest level of `ReadWriteMailbox`. I did this, but the API call is still failing.

I have sideloaded the add-in in a private development Microsoft 365 tenant, in which I have full admin rights to everything.

I would like to know:

- Have I done this incorrectly? If so, how should it be done?
- Has Microsoft deprecated the `Send` methods in favour of pushing everyone towards the Graph API instead?

Relevant parts of the addin manifest:

```xml
<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
</Hosts>

<Requirements>
    <Sets>
        <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
</Requirements>

<Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>

<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="ReadOrEdit" />
</Rule>

<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
            <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                        <Group id="Group.MessageRead">
                            <Label resid="Group.Label" />
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="HomeButton.MessageRead">
                                <!-- ... -->
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                </ExtensionPoint>
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                        <Group id="Group.MessageCompose">
                            <Label resid="Group.Label" />
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="HomeButton.MessageCompose">
                                <!-- ... -->
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                </ExtensionPoint>
            </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
    </Hosts>
</VersionOverrides>
```

JavaScript function that gets the email data (EWS API URL, EWS API token, selected item ID):

```js
var _getMailboxItem = function(onSuccess) {
    var ewsItemId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
    var afterSave = function() {
        var ewsUrl = Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl;
        Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({}, function(getCallbackTokenResult) {
            if(getCallbackTokenResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                _handleOfficeError(getCallbackTokenResult, "Cannot read the mailbox item.");
                return;
            }
            var ewsToken = getCallbackTokenResult.value;
            onSuccess({ url: ewsUrl, token: ewsToken, itemId: ewsItemId });
        });
    };
    if(ewsItemId) {
        // We have the item ID already, it's safe to continue.
        afterSave(onSuccess);
    } else {
        // We must save the item first before we can read data.
        console.log("Saving the item first...");
        Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function(saveAsyncResult) {
            if(saveAsyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                _handleOfficeError(saveAsyncResult, "Cannot save a draft of the mailbox item.");
                return;
            }
            ewsItemId = saveAsyncResult.value;
            afterSave(onSuccess);
        });
    }
};
```

Relevant controller code (ASP.NET MVC 4.8) to send a draft message:

```cs
private static ExchangeService GetExchangeService(MailboxItemModel mailboxItem) => new ExchangeService {
    Url = new Uri(mailboxItem.Url),
    Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(mailboxItem.Token)
};

private static EmailMessage GetEmailMessage(MailboxItemModel mailboxItem) => EmailMessage.Bind(
    GetExchangeService(mailboxItem),
    mailboxItem.ItemId,
    new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly) {
        ItemSchema.IsDraft,
        ItemSchema.IsUnmodified,
        ItemSchema.MimeContent
    });

private static void Send(EmailMessage emailMessage) {
    // Safety check: if the caller didn't pass an email message, then we can't do anything.
    if(emailMessage == null) { return; }
    // Safety check: only send if EWS confirms that the message is a draft.
    if(!emailMessage.IsDraft) { return; }
    emailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [EWS Tokens documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-mailbox-getcallbacktokenasync-member(1)), the token you retrieved and sent to your backend can be used for `GetItem` or `GetAttachments` in external systems.  That doesn't include sending email.

EWS calls can be made directly from the client part of the add-in using [`makeEwsRequestAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services). It is limited in what it can call and the `SendAndSaveCopy` method is not supported, though `CreateItem` and `SendItem` are.

The remaining option is to get a REST token (see that same document I mentioned first) and make a rest call that will allow you to send email.

Comment: Thanks Darren, I'll try getting a REST token and seeing what I can do with it.